# Symfony ManyToMany Query Builder Count returning wrong number

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to count books , that rely to a tag added within my system. 
The problem is, that i get a wrong number of counted books that have the same tag.

Book-Entity:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="books", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $tags;
```

Tag-Entity:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Book", inversedBy="tags")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="books_tags")
 */
protected $books;
```

Within my TagRepository, i have the following Code for Doctrine Query Builder:

```
 return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->innerJoin('t.books', 'b')
        ->addSelect('t.name')
        ->addSelect('t.id')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(b.id) AS amount')
        ->andWhere('t.name LIKE :name')
        ->setParameter('name', $term . '%')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

What is wrong with this query ? Why is it not counting the books that rely to one found tag ($term) right ?

Regards++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group your rows by adding `groupBy` statement:

```
 return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->innerJoin('t.books', 'b')
        ->addSelect('t.name')
        ->addSelect('t.id')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(b.id) AS amount')
        ->groupBy('t.id')
        ->andWhere('t.name LIKE :name')
        ->setParameter('name', $term . '%')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```